# Transaction lost between multiple transactionManager - Springboot 1.5.9

Tags: spring, transactionmanager

I have a problem with Spring-Boot-starter version 1.5.9-RELEASE
I declare multiple transaction manager with different CrudRepository and services.
Then I declare @transactionnal method with this order :

First Main transaction

```
Transactional(value = "innolaTransactionManager", readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
 public void integrateLdFilesData() {
```

Then call this method in it :

```
// Create transaction   
   DmTransaction transaction = transactionService.processTransaction(jacket.getTransactionNumber());
```

Then we enter a new method :

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, transactionManager = "dcToolTransactionManager")
 public DmTransaction processTransaction(String transactionNumber) {
  Transaction t = this.transactionRepository.findTransactionBytransactionNumber(transactionNumber);
  return this.createTransaction(t);
 }
```

Then I want to have a requires_new propagation but here my transaction will never commit at the end of this method

```
@Override
 @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, transactionManager = "innolaTransactionManager")
 public DmTransaction createTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
(...)
dmTransaction = dmTransactionRepository.save(dmTransaction);
  // Create objects in database
  return dmTransaction;
```

We debug this situation with log on jpa orm.

The only solution we came up with was to directly make change method processTransaction with requires_new after integrateLdFilesData method and delete third method createTransaction.

I think because we are using 2 transactionManager Spring lost transaction lifecycle somehow and don't commit even if we put a requires_new.

What do you think about that ?

Comment: Can you provide a [complete example](/help/mcve) that illustrates the problem? The relationship between the four snippets of code in your question isn't clear to me.

Comment: Spring uses proxies to apply AOP. Only method calls INTO the method pass through the proxy, you are doing internal method calls and hence those don't pass through the proxy. So basically your `@Transactional` is useless on that method.

Comment: So when I called this.createTransaction(t); then @Transactionnal is not taken into account ? 
When we use only 2 levels of method and transaction, this behaviour work even if we are in the same service calling another method from this service.